# grab followers from mongoose schema

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Basically I have a `User schema`. Within the schema I have the following item which contains the `id's` of all users. The `user` follows inside an array.

```
followers: [{
    type: String,
    required: false,
    unique: false
}],
```

My question is: **how do I get all the results from the followers array only so I can run a ng-repeat with them?**

This is what I have tried.

**Get Followers** controller:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('Scrimbox')

     .controller('GetFollowingController' 
       , ['$scope', '$http', 'User', '$routeParams', '$location'
       , function( $scope, $http, User, $routeParams, $location){ 

        $scope.following = function(){
            //Empty object to send to server
            var request = {};

            //get follower id
            var FollowerId = $routeParams.id;

            //bundle into the object to send to server
            var request = {
                follower: FollowerId
            };

            //send to server
            $http.post('api/social/getfollowing', request)
                .success(function(response){

            console.log(response);
            $scope.following = response.following;
        }).error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

    $scope.following();

    }]);
}());
```

**getfollowing** on the server:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../../models/UserModel');

module.exports.getfollowing = function(req, res){   
    var thefollower = req.body.follower;

    User.findOne({ _id: thefollower }).populate('_following').exec(function (err, user) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.json(err); 

            } else {
                console.log(user);
                res.jsonp(user);  
            }
    })
};
```

Called using:

```
app.post('/api/social/getfollowing', getfollowingController.getfollowing);
```

This is the response I get from the server:
[image: screenshot]

But how do I only get all the `ids` from the following array?

Then how do I use them for a `ng-repeat`?

Comment: How you have `followers`, and you populate `_following`? Try using a real reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Nathan, you only want the ids from the `followers` array right?

Comment: yes i only need the ids from the followers array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i did get this thanks for the responses.

i had to query the mongoDB for the user then create a variable for the followee's ID's then run a forEach Loop over all the IDs

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = require('../../models/UserModel'),
    async = require('async');


module.exports.getfollowing = function(req, res){

    //grab the Users ID from the body
    var thefollower = req.body.follower;

    //create empty array that i want to populate with the followee's ID and Avatar url
    var obj = [];

    //query mongo for the user
    User.findOne({ _id: thefollower }, function (err, user) {

            if (err) {

                console.log(err);
                res.json(err); 

            } else {

                //grab the following element of the users mongo schema -- should return all the followee's ID's -- tested works
                var following = user.following;

                //iritate throught all the followee's
                async.forEach(following, function(item, callback) {

                    //current followee
                    var user = item;

                    //query mongo for the followee
                    User.findOne({_id: user}, function(err, followee, callback){

                        //get followee's ID and Avatar url
                        var id = followee._id;
                        var avatar = followee.avatar;


                       //add the followee's ID and Avatar url to the obj array 
                       obj.push({                
                            id: id,
                            avatar: avatar                 
                       });

                    }); 

                    //see if this worked - returns empty
                    console.log(obj);
                    callback();

                }, function(err) {

                    //see if this worked - returns empty
                    console.log(obj);

                    //respond to the client - returns empty
                    res.json(obj);  

                });                  
            }   
    });  
};
```